# Squaring quantities with units

Tags: percentages

I am programming a script to an online store and a serious mathematical problem happened, and I cannot solve it!

This is the problem: if a person has only 10 cents (on any monetary currency, I will use US Dollar for example) it's the same as say that this person has $ 0.1 right?

I mean 10 cents = $ 0.1 , right?

Now, lets square it. The 10 cents becomes 100 cents, which is  1 dolar. Right? But 0.1*0.1 = $0.01.

I am very sure I can do this math using cents OR using any other unit I want and the result should be the same. If I have the same example and I want to make the square with a number that is in meters and other is in kilometer. The result should be the same, but it is not! What is the issue here?

EDIT:

One final question, a function with $x^3$ should increase faster than $x^2$ right?

For example, $2^2 = 4$ and $2^3 = 8$
$10^2 = 100$ and $10^3 = 100$

So the $x^3$ graphic should always be on top of $x^2$. Why doesnt that happen all the time?

OBS: this edit looks not related to my main question but it is completely, depending on the answer.

Comment: The units change when you square things - one square dollar = 10,000 square cents - just like one square metre = 10,000 square centimetres

Comment: The meaning of square money is for example you can square an interest rate montly. The other meaning is that it's easier to me save the cents in a database instead of the 0.1 cause integer operations in SQL is muh faster than float maths.

Comment: An interest rate, in the form $1+r$ where $100r$ is the percentage rate, is a dimensionless ratio between the sum of money at the end and the sum at the beginning

Comment: *taking mental note of carefully checking the units before shopping at sitepor500.com.br*

Comment: @MarkBennet the interest rate in my case was converted to money units, I mean instead of an interest rate of % it was converted to an interest rate of % x \$^-1 = %/$  . Squaring this will generate the problem I reported

Comment: @mickep how do I change my username? I didnt even create an account, I just posted the question using my email! How did SE get my link?

Comment: If you keep correct track of the units - and your last comment is unclear - you will find that the problem disappears.

Comment: You have a link "Edit Profile & Settings" on your Profile page.

Comment: $x^3$ grows larger at infinity, but it is only actually bigger in magnitude if $|x|>1$. If $|x|<1$ then it is actually smaller, because multiplication by a number of magnitude less than $1$ makes the number smaller.

Comment: I was scared by your title at sight ....

Comment: So this is what happened in 2008.

Comment: Square dollars. Now I've seen it all.

Comment: If there are units of currency occurring _anywhere_ in your interest rates, you're doing it wrong. Plainly and simply wrong. Go back and correct whatever mistaken idea caused the $\$^{-1}$ to sneak into your interest rate, correct or re-do everything that was affected by that mistaken idea, and be careful not to make that mistake again.

Comment: -1 for the blatantly false premise. I can imagine no circumstances under which an online store would need to square amounts of money.

Comment: @MarkBennet So a square dollar equals 10,000 square cents? I am scared.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is you aren't keeping track of the units properly. $(10\textrm{ cents})^2=100\textrm{ cents}^2$ whereas $(\$0.1)^2=\$^20.01$. Note that since $100\textrm{ cents}=\$1$, we have that $10000\textrm{ cents}^2=\$^21$. Using this unit conversion, the equality that looked weird to you holds.

Comment: AMAZING!!! I SPENT MANY DAYS INTO THIS!!! Thank you A LOT! I will save the squared unit in my database and make sure when I change to another unit I make the correct conversion!

Comment: @Sitepor500.com.br Glad to be helpful :)

Comment: @Sitepor500.com.br consider accepting this answer to let other users know that this is the right one.

Comment: @SalmonKiller Not necessarily that it is the *right* one per se but the most helpful ;)

Comment: I am trying to accept this answer but SE says I need to wait more 6 minutes. I will do that :) I am very glad to you.

Comment: @MagicMan yeah, that's what I meant to say :)

Answer (score 6):

The calculation is correct (though you have named the units incorrectly).

I doubt you have a problem with the fact that 1 yard = 3 feet, but 1 square yard = 9 square feet. It's the same sort of thing.

Comment: You are right, I edited the question can you help me answer the bottom of it?

Comment: It's unrelated. You should pose it as another question. Piggybacking questions is frowned upon. Post another and I will read it.

Answer (score 4):

If you square 10 cents, then you have 100 "square-cents".
If you square 0.1 Dollar, then you have 0.01 "square-Dollars".
Now, 100 "square-cents" is the same as 0.01 "square-Dollars".

Maybe it's not such a good idea to square money...

Comment: squaring money is needed in my case cause I need it to calculate intererest rate of a purchase that is made in several months. I use a strange formula from my customers that squares everything including the money, not only the interest rate.

Comment: It is a good idea to never pass around raw numbers or strings in code for this reason.  It's the main reason why constructors exist:  d := Dollar(0.1); c := Cents(d.toCents()).

Answer (score 2):

Although there are many correct answers already posted, I'd like to post an answer that is easier to read and conceptualize.

If you have \$0.10 and you want to collect ten of them, then the calculation is simple: "10 x \$0.10 = \$1", which is what you expect.

Conversely, when you say you want to "square" ten cents, what you're really saying is you want to "ten cents the ten cents", which doesn't make any sense.

Alternatively, if you view each cent as one percent (which is where the term "percent" came from, "per cent" or "per one hundred"), ten cents is thus 10%, which if squared, means "10% of 10%", which is 1%.

Comment: I never heard that analogy that percent is "per cent". Really nice man. Great explanation

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to *square* the money (otherwise, the unit would change from cents or $\$$ to cents^2 or $\$^2$, and the result you get in these units is not a contradiction); more likely, you expect a result tantamount to *multiplying* the amount by 10.

Comment: But I need to use interest rate that was converted from % to $ that's why I need to square it. Can you also help me answer the bottom of my question?

Comment: % is a ratio without units (call it the unit 1).  90% could come from: (9 dollars)/(10 dollars) = 0.9 = 90%.  If you want a percentage of an original amount:  \$600 * 90%, which is in dollars.  ((\$600 * 90%) * 90% )* 90%) = \$600 * (90% * 90% * 90%) is in dollars as well.  Notice that the rate keeps getting exponentiated, not the dollars.

Comment: For you last question: $x^3 > x^2$ when $x > 1$; [the behavior is opposite for $0 \leq x <1$.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7Bx%5E2%2Cx%5E3%7D%2C+x%3D0..1.5)